# Storing huge number of records in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I have a list with more than 50K entities attached to it. I have to store each entity as a row in DB .

To Store them I'm traversing list and then calling below function for each node

```
public Serializable create(T entity) throws MyCustomExc{
    Serializable serializable = null;
    try{
        Session session = getHibernateSession();
        session.save(entity);
    }catch(HibernateException e){
        throw new MyCustomExc("Error...."+entity,e);
    }
return serializable;
}
```

The issue is I'm getting error like this

```
JDBCException E org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-964, SQLSTATE=57011, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=3.62.56
```

which basically means "running out of space in the transaction log."
Now, I can't change any of the transaction log properties.

In hibernate autocommit property is false.

What is the issue here?? Should I change it from "session.save(entity)" to "session.persist(entity)". Let me know if any other info is needed.

Comment: Have you tried committing your transaction from time to time (every 10, 100, 1000 or any other number of object creation)?

Comment: I thought of that but the issue is it's happening in the live environment and I can't replicate it on my local machine.  Hence, I need advice which is sureshot

Comment: From my experience, Hibernate is not the proper framework to do batch job. Your option is to commit TX partially as @StephaneM mentioned or use pure JDBC if possible.

Comment: While I agree Hibernate is a poor fit for this problem, the fact that this is a DB2 exception suggests the problem is at the DB2 side, not (yet) with Hibernate. Indeed committing more often (or, probably, just starting a completely new transaction every now and then) would be my approach - but as long as you can't reproduce this locally, you won't find a "sureshot solution".